# NPE in search example in youtube API

Tags: java

i'm trying to execute code from here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword but im getting NPE in line 96 of my code:

```
YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
```

Do you have any idea why? 
my code is modified a little bit - imports at the begining and line:

```
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
```

to

```
new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
```

my entire code is  [here](http://pastebin.com/DHTZCt9Z)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)